# couchdb don't start on server reboot

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-10.04, init.d

I've using the standard init.d script that comes with CouchDB. I'm using it on Ubuntu.

On server restart, this is printed on local console:

```
 * Starting database server couchdb                                    [ OK ]
```

So, it's assumed that CouchDB was started, but not. CouchDB is not started.

I must log into the server and start service with `service couchdb start`, then CouchDB was started correctly.

Any idea in how to debug why CouchDB is not started on reboot ? Already done the `update-rc.d` command.

Comment: Nothing. It seems that CouchDB was never executed. But, only when server reboot.